# Built in functionality to split queue by partition and process one at a time

Tags: azure, queue

We have a situation where we could get thousands of requests coming in at the same time and we need to process each request immediately then add it to a queue

The queue then needs to be split by a client id and all data on the queue needs to be processed one by one, i.e. not allowing the default functionality of picking up several items off the queue and processing them in parallel

We are using Azure Functions so have access to all of the triggers

Is there anything built in to queues that I might have missed?

Paul